# How to calculate the sum of all values in a dictionary excluding the first item's value?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have a dictionary of (string, decimal) and need to calculate the sum of all the Values (decimal values) starting from the second item. Is it achievable using LINQ?

Comment: Since it is a dictionary, what is the first element ? A standard dictionary is not ordered,what you pick up in a certain moment can change by adding other keys...

Comment: You have to first force an order in your dictionary. If by "the second" you mean "the second lowest decimal value stored", use myDict.SortBy (x => x.Value).Skip (1).

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand that the dictionary does not preserve the order and need to do some sorting as Elideb mentioned.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Very achievable using LINQ:

```
myDict.Skip(1).Sum(x => x.Value);
```

However, the standard `Dictionary` class doesn't guarantee ordering of items, so the "first" item can be anything.

Comment: How about myDict.OrderBy (x => x.Key).Skip (1).Sum (x => x.Value); ? Replace order selector with whatever suits you.

Comment: @Agree with Elideb, avoiding a sort is a source of really nasty bag, If no sort appy ( ie the inserto order is neeeded ) maybe having a dictionary is the wrong data structure

Answer (score 7):

Why not just sum them all up, then subtract the first item?

```
myList.Sum(x => x.Value) - myList.First().Value;
```

Comment: How to access first item in dictionary? It does not preserve the order

Comment: I belive myList.First() could return different value whilst calling multiple times so you can consider some item as `First` in scope of single LINQ query, so this approach could be wrong, correct me please if I wrong

Answer (score 3):

Skip the first element thusly;

```
dict.Skip(1).Sum(ix => ix.Value);
```

Comment: You seem to be summing the `string` _keys_ rather than the `double` _values_.

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough to do using LINQ:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

dict.Add("A", 1.5m); // This value will be skipped
dict.Add("B", 2.7m);
dict.Add("C", 1.3m);
dict.Add("D", 3.9m);

var total = dict.Skip(1).Sum(v => v.Value);

Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the key of the first item and exclude it from the sum:

```
dict.Sum(T => T.Key == "FirstKey" ? 0 : T.Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

To get sum of your `TValue` items

```
total = d.Skip(0).Sum(x => x.Value)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? `Skip(0)`? And if it was supposed to be `Skip(1)`, please note that the other answers already say exactly the same thing.