# Summing Properties of Values in a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have something like this

```
Dictionary<String, Profile > sto;
```

where Profile is a class with different properties (eg. int Ints). Now I want to know whether there is a command that sums all Ints over the whole Dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I don't see anything wrong with this question. ( maybe the first/last line can be removed)

Comment: Do you mean that there may be more than one property on the `Profile` class of type `int` that you want to sum?  The question as it stands is still rather unclear.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Really? This question is nothing more than 3 seconds needed to ask google something like "c# dictionary sum value". So I don't really think it's valuable "ontopic question" at SO.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Right. it's also a dup. then vote to close it instead of downvote ( not saying you did , but just pointing to why downvote is wrong here).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the sum of all values in a dictionary excluding the first item's value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128477/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-all-values-in-a-dictionary-excluding-the-first-item)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I said : _not saying you did , but just pointing to why downvote is wrong here_

Comment: FWIW, I downvoted it.  "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @JamesThorpe By strict rules , you are right. but he is a new member ( only from today). I think 3 scary downvotes could be saved from that guy. maybe i'm wrong , I don't know. we are all human.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Hence my comment attempting to gain additional info to add more context that may turn it from a simple google into something potentially involving reflection etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Well ...never-mind. it's a dup anyway....

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `Sum` method:

```
int sum = sto.Sum(x => x.Value.SomeIntProperty);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
var sum = sto.Sum(x=>x.Value.PropertyName);
```

The `PropertyName` is a property of `Profile` class that is of type `int`.